# How to force fixed position of lines and gaps pattern in SLD/YLSD with stroke-dasharray or stroke-graphic

Tags: geoserver, sld, ysld

Any kind of dashed effects (simple line or svg/image symbols on line) are rendered correctly at fixed position if the whole line or its start point are currently visible. If we move the map view that the start point of line is outside of it, the line pattern will be shifted like this:

```
name: LINE
title: LINE
feature-styles:
- rules:
  - name: LINE
    symbolizers:
    - line:
        uom: metre
        stroke-color: '#000000'
        stroke-width: 0.5
        stroke-linejoin: bevel
        stroke-linecap: butt
        stroke-dasharray: 0.75 0.25
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

On first picture the line start point is bottom left and the line is all visible on map. Its starts from 0.75m dash and after that 0.25m gap and so on. At the of the line end top-right it ends with 0.25 gap. If I move the map a little bit down so the start of my line isn't visible, the end of my line is not ending with a 0.25 gap (picture 2, 3).

Is there any way to force fixed position of `stroke-dasharray` or `stroke-graphic` pattern?

Below SVG example: 1 whole line visible (correct); 2,3 part of line visible (incorrect/shifted).

[image]

Comment: could you add some other feature or a base map in your images to make what is happening clearer?

Comment: On firs picture the line start point is bottom left and it's all visible on map. Its starts from 0.75m dash and after that 0.25m gap and so on.

Comment: but all those images look to be what I would expect from moving the map

Comment: I put a more illustrative example from SVG. I am trying to create a map displaying e.g. road markings - the order of lines and gaps is very important here.

Comment: I think you are "misusing" the graphic fill - if the symbol should be at a fixed point then you should use a Point and an External Graphic to place it in that place

Comment: The svg example is also line symbolizer but just more complicated: two offsetted vertical lines, one repeated horizontal SVG line symbol and intersecting X SVG lines symbol. All of them repeated every 2 meters of line. So I just want to the line symbolizer looks always like at picture 1 regardless of whether the entire line is visible on the map or not.